# Team Fortress 2: Hidden Stats on Capture Points for Payload Cart pushing

Tags: team-fortress-2

The only information I found is this: https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Scoreboard#Points

"Pushing the Payload cart for 10 seconds" gives you 1 capture point which will give you 2 overall score points.

However sometimes I feel like I'm pushing the cart for 30 seconds and I don't get a single point. What's going on here? The 10 second rule certainly isn't true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every player gets 0.1 capture points for every second they push the cart. This does not have to be continuous, or even in the same life, but it does have to be unblocked. It doesn't matter what class you are, what your capture multiplier is, or how many other players are on the cart. Only once your amount of capture points reaches the next whole number does it count, so in essence you get 1 capture point every 10 seconds.

However, this is a mapper-defined value ("partial capture rate"); mapmakers can decide to raise or lower this rate, so some maps can have faster or slower rates of giving out capture points. On most official payload maps this value is 0.1 (hence 10 seconds being the conventional wisdom), but a few are different - for example, it's 0.02 on Upward, so there you have to push the cart for a full 50 seconds to get one capture point.

Comment: Where did you get this information from?

Comment: Opening (decompiled) maps in the Hammer editor, then checking the partial capture rate value of the map's `team_control_point_master`.

Comment: I've noticed it was 15 seconds on Badwater. Different on all maps. If we could get a list for all payload maps that would be wicked